# How can I export a variable/string (URL specific) from discord message to the JS file?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, puppeteer

I would like to know how to export a string (an URL) from message discord chat to the JS file and use it as a variable. I'm testing some scraping on my website.
E.G.:

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {
if(msg.content === "!command " + "URL typed on discord chat" (example "https://www.Google.com") {
[...puppeteer stuff] 
await page.goto(the URL I typed on discord chat, in this case "https://www.Google.com")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {
    // check if the message starts with '!command'
    if(msg.content.startsWith("!command")) {
        // splits message by spaces
        // and gets second item in the array
        // ["!command", "https://example.com", "foo"]
        //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // which should be an URL
        const url = msg.content.split(/\s+/)[1];
        // puppeteer stuff
        await page.goto(url);
    }
})
```